# Make script executable from within Geany

Tags: bash, executable, geany

I edit and test a lot of scripts using Geany.

Is there a way to make an open script executable using Geany instead of having to do it using my file manager?

Comment: Is «executable» a word to say «setting the permission» of an open file?

Answer (score 1):

I defined a build command.

Under Build

Set Build Commands

No filetype commands

Set Exe Bit                            chmod +x %f

Comment: I could not find "No filetype commands" but I suppose you can choose which group you like to add the command to.